# Basic premise on counting sort. How is k related to to Big Oh?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, theory, sorting

I am reading (Cormen) on counting sort.
I understand the structure of the algorithm but the statement:

> In practice, we usually use counting sort when we have k = O(n), in
>   which case the running time is Theta(n).

Is not clear to my mind.

k is just the range of integers expected in the input.

Why is the asymptotic notation used in this statement for k? I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

Your quote is saying that if the range of integers k is linearly proportional to the total number of elements in the collection n, then a counting sort will have a best-case and a worst-case time complexity of O(n), making it a very efficient sort in such a case.

Big Oh (and others in the Bachman-Landau family of notations) are just simplifications of the precise complexity of the function in any given case, used to illustrate the increasing value of the function as N grows large. In programming, Big Oh is usually used in the context of time complexity; for n values, a function f(n) will execute in a time on the order of g(n), and thus we say it has a Big Oh complexity of O(g(n)). However the mathematical construct of Big Oh isn't so limited. In this particular case, it is being used to refer to the general relationship between k and N as numbers.

Simply put, when k (the range of the values of an n-element collection) increases as n does on the order of O(n), then the counting sort will be efficient. This will be true if, say, the list contained all multiples of 4 between 1 and x (in which case k~=x, and n=x/4, meaning that k ~= 4n = O(n)). The condition k=O(n) would be false for, say, the set of all perfect squares from 1 to x<sup>2</sup> (in which case k=x<sup>2</sup> but n=x, so k = n<sup>2</sup> = O(n<sup>2</sup>)). In that case, k increases on the square (O(n<sup>2</sup>)) when N increases linearly (O(n)), so the counting sort would execute in the more complex time (which would be O(n<sup>2</sup>)), which would perform worse than some other sort implementation that ran in Theta(nlogn).

Comment: Not sure I get this.E.g. if x=256 then a list containing all multiples of 4 between 1 and x is [1,4,14,64,256].I guess k is the largest so k=256.Why is n=x/4?In this case it is n=256/4=64 but we only have 5 elements.I am trying to understand what you are saying here

Comment: Uh, no. The list of all multiples of 4 between 1 and 256 is [4,8,12,16,20, ... 240,248,252,256]. This list will have n=64 elements and an inclusive range of k=253. This is on the order of k=4n-3, which in Big Oh terms is linear (O(n)). However, a list of the first N perfect squares would have a range k=n^2. As k increases on the square of n, the counting sort, which executes in time proportionate to the larger of k and n, will become less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of a counting sort is O(max(k, n)), so if k = O(n) the sort runs in O(n) time.

Comment: That is my question.What does `k=O(n)` mean in this context?

Comment: It means that for k is no greater than some constant multiple of n.

Answer (score 0):

At least as I interpret it, it's just saying that the range of the inputs and the number of inputs are kinda similar [Edit: least that be misunderstood, it's giving that as the condition under which the complexity is Theta(n), not saying that it's necessarily always true.]

Just for example, the usual estime is reasonable for a thousand or a million or a billion inputs of something like 32 or 64 bits each.

Ignoring, for the moment, the fact that you'd never actually finish, consider what would happen if you have a 500-digit (or 10,000 digit) number of 3-bit inputs. In such a case, the time taken to do each individual addition could start to become significant [Edit: I.e., would no longer be constant], so Theta(n) would no longer be accurate. In the usual case, we can ignore the time for the additions because it's a constant factor.

Comment: Actually, it's saying that IF the range of inmputs and the number of inputs are similar, that a counting sort will be efficient.